# Google Maps to display only a country or state

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What features of the Google Maps API would one use to display a single country or state, that is static, and has location markers?

Answer (score 2):

When I am using Google Static Maps I use the website below.  It makes creating these maps a whole lot easier.

**Static Map Generator**

http://staticmapmaker.com/

If you want to take the long route you can use the API.  Also, it helps to use the generator and make further changes to the map by referencing the API.  Despite what you read on the API you do not need an API key to generate the maps.

**Google Static Maps API**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/